# Set timeout for screensaver in javascript

Tags: javascript, screensaver

I want to create a screensaver in JavaScript but I don't know how can I set the time between the images,.

I have an Ajax call and I see if the time is, for example, 2s or 90s, but I don't know how to set that time between images, this is my code:

```
  var cont = 0;
  var time = 1000
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(tiempo);
    if(cont == imagenes.length){
      return cont = 0;
    }else{
      var imagen = imagenes[cont].imagen;
      $('#imgZona').attr('src', imagen);
      var time = imagenes[cont].tiempoVisible;
      finalTime = Number(time);
    }
    cont++;
  }, Number(finalTime ));
```

but the time between images is always the same, 1000, how can I change it for the time that I receive in the Ajax call? Which is `imagenes[cont].tiempoVisible`

Answer (score 1):

Control set every timeout on each iteration.

```
  var cont = 0;
  var time = 1000
  function next () {
    console.log(tiempo);
    if(cont == imagenes.length){
      cont = 0;
    }
    var imagen = imagenes[cont].imagen;
    $('#imgZona').attr('src', imagen);
    cont++;
    setTimeout(next, Number(imagenes[cont].tiempoVisible));
  }
  setTimeout(next, Number(initialTime));
```

Also I fixed a frindge condition.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment as I don't have enough reputation, but take a look at this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kidino/4mbpR/

```
var mousetimeout;
var screensaver_active = false;
var idletime = 5;

 function show_screensaver(){
   $('#screensaver').fadeIn();
   screensaver_active = true;
   screensaver_animation();
 }

function stop_screensaver(){
   $('#screensaver').fadeOut();
  screensaver_active = false;
}

function getRandomColor() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
   var color = '#';
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
     color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
  }
  return color;
 }

$(document).mousemove(function(){
    clearTimeout(mousetimeout);

 if (screensaver_active) {
    stop_screensaver();
}

mousetimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    show_screensaver();
    }, 1000 * idletime); // 5 secs          
});

function screensaver_animation(){
 if (screensaver_active) {
    $('#screensaver').animate(
        {backgroundColor: getRandomColor()},
        400,
        screensaver_animation);
   }
}
```

It will change background-color on idle mouse for 5 seconds, you can replace the code to change image, instead of background color.